# Remove launch screen if device version in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8

I have an application which works for iOS 7 and 8 and I'm using auto layout so it will be ok on all iPhones. For iOS 7 I need the launch screen file but for iOS 8 I want to hide it. 
How can I remove it specifically for iOS 8?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: +(NSInteger) iosMajorVersion
    {
        NSArray *versionComponents = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        return [versionComponents[0] integerValue];
    }
    
    +(BOOL) isIOS8
    {
     return [self iosMajorVersion] >= 8;
    }

Comment: @hariszaman thanks, I am using these methods in my app delegate but I can not call them, would you please post an answer and write the code for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The launch screen is processed and displayed by iOS before anything else happens. You can't do anything programmatically to affect the launch screen as your code won't run until after the launch screen has been displayed.

So the only thing you can do is take advantage of the xib launch screen support introduced with iOS8, to provide two different launch screens: one for iOS8+ (the xib) and one for iOS7 and lower (the png).

Answer (score 1):

In the [HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html) it says the following...

> In iOS 8 and later, you can create a XIB or storyboard file instead of
>   a static launch image...

..

> If you also need to support earlier versions of iOS, you can continue to supply static launch images in addition to a launch file.